# how do Instantiate one by one?

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine

I want to Instantiate units one by one.

```
void Update() {
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    Enemies[] enemies = stage.enemies;
    if (timer >= 0) {
        Vector3 enemyPos = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, Random.Range (-5.0f, 5.0f), transform.position.z);
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < enemies[i].count; j++) {
                print (enemies.Length);
                print (enemies[i].count);
                GameObject spawn = Instantiate (enemyPrefeb, enemyPos, Quaternion.identity);

                timer = delayTimer;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

da
i used double for loop. The present state spawn 10 units(in DB) like one unit.(Overlap)

how to fix it?

i want spawn one by one with delay.

Comment: Check [this](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/1304244/instantiating-grid-of-objects-starting-at-the-bott.html) for different positioning. And for timing, you can create you own timer or use [coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it like this (this spawns one enemy per second):

```
float delayTimer = 1;

void Update() {
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    Enemies[] enemies = stage.enemies;
    if (timer >= delayTimer) {
        Vector3 enemyPos = new Vector3 (transform.position.x, Random.Range (-5.0f, 5.0f), transform.position.z);
        GameObject spawn = Instantiate (enemyPrefeb, enemyPos, Quaternion.identity);
        timer = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < enemies.Length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < enemies[i].count; j++) {
                print (enemies.Length);
                print (enemies[i].count);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

you mistaken two lines, you have to check if timer is as high as delayTimer and then spawn the enmy and reset timer to 0.